# Understanding repeated measures GLM

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, repeated-measures

I am trying to understand how to perform ANOVAs with general linear models, but got stuck with repeated measures.

Using the [example data from here](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/repeated-measures-anova-statistical-guide-2.php):

$$
\begin{matrix}
\mathrm{subject} & \mathrm{pre} & \mathrm{3mo} & \mathrm{6mo} \\
1 & 45 & 50 & 55 \\
2 & 42 & 42 & 45 \\
3 & 36 & 41 & 43 \\
4 & 39 & 35 & 40 \\
5 & 51 & 55 & 59 \\
6 & 44 & 49 & 56
\end{matrix}
$$

With dummy variables for each factor level and each subject I construct linear equations of the form $Ax=b$ with
$$
A = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& & & &\vdots \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right],
b = \left[
\begin{matrix}
45 \\ 50 \\55 \\42 \\ 42 \\ \vdots \\44 \\49 \\56
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Solving for $x$ leads to the following sums of squares:
$$
\mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{residual} = \sum_i (A_ix - b_i)^2 = 57.2 \\
\mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{model} = \sum_i (A_ix - \bar{b})^2 = 801.7
$$

However, the expected ANOVA results are:
$$
\mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{error} = \mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{within} - \mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{subject} = 715.5 - 658.3 = 57.2 \\
\mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{between} = 143.4
$$

The residual/error sum of squares agree, but the model's sum of squares is too high. I guess that it contains both, the variation explained by the factor and the inter-subject variability, while I am interested in the former alone.

Subtracting $\mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{subject}$ from $\mathrm{SoS}_\mathrm{model}$ gives the expected result of 143.4. Why is this the case? And how how can one get the ANOVA result using the linear model alone?